# Duplicated request, need an advice please

Tags: laravel

I made a system to calculate the total price of a basket, it works but I saw that there were duplicate requests, I would like to share the code with you to know if you would have done otherwise?
For the moment I have not found any other solution.

**Userscontroller.php :**

```
$carts =\Auth::user()->carts;
```

**User.php (model) :**

```
public function carts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Cart')->with('product');
}
```

**Cart.php (model) :**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'product_id')->with('productCat');
}

public function getTotalPrice()
{
    $price = 0;
    foreach($this->user->carts as $carts)
    {
        $price += $carts->getPriceByQuantity();
    }
    return $price;
}

public function getPriceByQuantity()
{
    $quantity = $this->quantity;
    $price = ($this->product->product_total_price == '') ? $this->product->priceRender() : $this->product->product_total_price;
    return $price * $quantity;
}
```

The problem is that i declare user->carts one time in userscontroller for the view, and one time in getTotalPrice. Before, i wanted to loop over **$this** instead of **$this->user->carts**, but the loop was repeated by the quantity number of a product.

If someone knows the best way to do this ? Thank you

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but it hit me that by `Cart`, you mean cart item right? It's very confusing to use the notion of cart to refer to a cart item.

Comment: oh i should use basket ? i'm french :)

Comment: More like you should use "cart item" instead of "cart" (or "basket item" instead of "basket"). Because when we say cart, we normally expect it to be able to contain many cart items (products). But based on your `Cart` model definition, you're treating cart the same way we treat as cart item. Anyway that just might be my pet peeve. I don't expect you to take it seriously. ;)

Comment: Oh okay haha, no actually i make a cart by groupBy user_id, so yes, i got many products for one cart, but i was thinking to translate that with a pivot, you right